# I have two microservice, should it have its independent embedded tomcat or one common tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

Which is good in production environment? Individual embedded tomcat for each app or one tomcat for many apps?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of making micro services is mainly to build services that are developed/ deployed/scaled independently. When you try to deploy multiple microservices inside a same container/jvm then you may not be able to leverage all these benefits. Also you CI/CD/integration testing may be hard. Try using embedded containers or container technologies like Docker which ensures complete isolation of the microservices.

The decision also depends on what is the deployment environment of yours. If its cloud going for Docker would be a good idea

Comment: For PCF try using embedded containers. Spring boot jar with embedded containers can be directly pushed(cf push) in CF with java buildpacks.  This has worked for me very well in the past.